# Android: Is there anything good about giving id to all the views?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm studying Android by looking at open source projects code, and what I noticed was that, in many cases, they give ids to almost all the views, even if they don't actually use those ids in code.
For example, they give ids to `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout` and so on, but they don't really use those ids in code.

Is there any reason why they do that?
Because I think giving ids to all the views only makes me confused about what id was what view.
Is it just a bad practice?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any reason why they do that?

No.

Technically there is no reason to do that if you are not going to use the `id` anywhere   (either in `Java` or in the `XML` file).

For eg it could be a personal choice, just like naming variables or naming class depending on its purpose (here note that this could be a personal choice).

From the developer API guides:

> Defining IDs for view objects is important when creating a
>   RelativeLayout. In a relative layout, sibling views can define their
>   layout relative to another sibling view, which is referenced by the
>   unique ID.

Again,

> Because I think giving ids to all the views only makes me confused
>   about what id was what view.

You can easily sort out the confusion thing if you give proper name to the id's.
Like:

`btn_create` for **Buttons**

`tv_mobile_number` for **TextViews**

`ll_main_activity` for **LinearLayouts**

`rl_details_fragment` for **RelativeLayouts** and so on.

> Is it just a bad practice?

Technically not. But it may save you from the pain of typing id's for each and every view and may even save some time for you as well.

As a side note, I usually prefer giving `id's` only when needed.

Hope this will help you. Cheers!

Comment: So it was just individuals' preferences. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

sure it some times confused, in my case I give id only to views that I will use in codes.
thank.